# MySQL: select two column from the same table with the same name

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm creating an application to manage `game` and `team` data. Here is mySQL db structure:

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE game (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_team_A INT NOT NULL,
    id_team_B INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- TEST VALUES: --

INSERT INTO team VALUES
    (1, "Barcelona"),
    (2, "Milan"),
    (3, "Real Madrid"),
    (4, "Inter");

INSERT INTO game VALUES
    (1, 1, 3),
    (2, 2, 4);
```

As you can see every `match` has 2 different `team` associated.

I'm trying (without success) to get in a single query **match id, team A name, team B name**.

First I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT game.id, team.name, team.name
FROM team INNER JOIN game
ON game.id_team_A = team.id;
```

But my query don't care about `match.id_team_B` and duplicated `match.name` fields won't solve the problem.

Then I started using select query nested together:

```
SELECT @g_id := game.id as id,
(SELECT team.name FROM team INNER JOIN game ON game.id_team_A = team.id WHERE game.id = @g_id) AS team_A,
(SELECT team.name FROM team INNER JOIN game ON game.id_team_B = team.id WHERE game.id = @g_id) AS team_B
FROM game;
```

And finally I got what I wanted:

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
| id  |    team_A     |    team_B     |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  1  |   Barcelona   |  Real Madrid  |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  2  |     Milan     |     Inter     |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
```

**Is there an easier/faster/cooler query to got the same result?**

NOTE: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e477ae/12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do joins between the same table, so you can do it like:

```
SELECT g.id as id, a.name as team_a, b.name as team_b 
FROM team a INNER JOIN game g ON g.id_team_A = a.id
INNER JOIN team b ON g.id_team_B = b.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You need two alias:

```
SELECT g.id, t1.name team_A, t2.name team_B
FROM game g, team t1, team t2
WHERE g.id_team_A = t1.id AND g.id_team_B = t2.id
```

Or with join:

```
SELECT g.id, t1.name team_A, t2.name team_B
FROM game g JOIN team t1 ON g.id_team_A = t1.id
JOIN team t2 ON g.id_team_B = t2.id
```

Comment: Actually one alias would be just fine as then there would not be a name clash